# Visual Code (NODE JS) debugging - variables are invisible

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have problem with my project's back-end written in `Node JS`. I use `Visual Code`.
I can't debug it, I can use breakpoints, but when program stops, I see nothing in "Variables" frame.

Before I run Visual Code, I used nodemon plugin. It starts on port `3000` and debugging on `5858`.

I tried to set port `3000` or `5858` in launch.json in Visual Code, but during debugging I can only stop on breakpoints and no variables are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have latest node  **v0.12.7**

When i had this problem, updating from 0.10.35 to 0.12.76 resolved it.